# Dynamically updating Tkinter widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

For an application in which I control various sensors connected to the Raspberry I created a Python script that reads and updates the values ​​of the various sensors by reporting them on some labels of a graphical interface created with tkinter.

The graphic interface consists of a "START" button and various labels to collect the values ​​read by the various sensors.

By clicking on "START" in the relevant routine, in addition to various configuration actions and various settings, the values ​​of around twenty analog sensors are sequentially read and written in the labels relating to the various sensors.

The problem I encounter is that the labels are updated only at the end of the START button management routine when it re-enters the mainloop, therefore the script, with regards to the control and reading of the sensor values, works correctly, and at the end I have the situation updated values, unfortunately since the reading of the sensors takes a certain time, about 20 seconds, you have the sensation that once you click START nothing happens for 20 seconds (sometimes even longer because some sensors can have longer response times).

To do some checks I wrote a very light script which I report below (the production script with all the sensor management part is very heavy):

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def StartMain():
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(1)
        lbl01.config(text=i)
        print(i)
    
def ResMain():
            lbl01.config(text="")

mainw = tk.Tk()
mainw.title("SyncLBL")
mainw.geometry("500x100+400+300")
mainw.resizable(False, False)

lbl01 = ttk.Label(text="",borderwidth=5, relief="ridge")
lbl01.grid(column=3, row=1,sticky="EW",padx=5,pady=2,ipadx=50, ipady=5)

StartButton=ttk.Button(text="START",command=StartMain)
StartButton.grid(column=0,row=3,sticky="EW",padx=5,pady=2,ipadx=50, ipady=5)

ResButton=ttk.Button(text="RESET",command=ResMain)
ResButton.grid(column=5,row=3,sticky="EW",padx=5,pady=2,ipadx=50, ipady=5)
mainw.mainloop()
```

When I click on the START button in the console I see the count increase every second while the interface label is updated only at the end of the START routine with the last count value.

How can I see the label updated as the counting continues?

Comment: For the 10 second duration of your `StartMain()` function, *you do not have a functioning GUI* - the mainloop is not executing, so no events are being processed.  You must do a small bit of work at a time, and then return to the mainloop.  If there's more to do later, call `.after()` to schedule it to be done, some number of milliseconds later.

Comment: As you said, when `StartMain()` is being executed, the tkinter `mainloop()` is blocked from  handling pending updates and events.  Call `lbl01.update()` after `lbl01.config(...)` to force the update.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I added the mainw.update() line after reading the sensors and the interface is updated immediately as I wanted.
Perfect!!
The suggestion to divide the script into different threads will certainly be correct but I believe that having already written the entire program, modifying it in this sense is quite complicated, I will take the suggestion into account on future occasions by setting the script in this way from the beginning.
Anyway, thank you all for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

If your sensor takes more than a few hundred milliseconds, the only way to create a responsive GUI is to check the sensor in a separate thread or process.

You can start a thread to gather data and then immediately return so that `mainloop` can continue to process events. This other thread can send a virtual event to the main thread when the data is ready. You can then bind to the virtual event in the main thread to get the data from a thread-safe queue and update the UI. Or, your main GUI thread can simply poll the queue once every few hundred milliseconds and update the UI when data is ready.